# Docker build: read-only file system

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm using a `Dockerfile` to build my image and I have a command in there that says:

```
RUN sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1
```

but it fails to build the image with the following error:

```
Step 20 : RUN sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1
 ---> Running in 4d7302b56c53
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.route.flush": Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For security reasons, you need to be in privileged mode for this operation. It is not currently possible to use a Dockerfile with the privileged mode.

```
$> docker run ubuntu sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1 && echo ok || echo ko
sysctl: setting key "net.ipv4.route.flush": Read-only file system
ko
$> docker run --privileged ubuntu sysctl -w net.ipv4.route.flush=1 && echo ok || echo ko
ok
```

Why do you need to do this at build time?

Comment: This affect the host, so if you are doing it as buildtime, it won't be applied the the host running the actual container.

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to your exact situation, but I was receiving `read-only file system` notices frequently when trying to do a number of operations involving writes:

- `docker build`
- `docker rmi`
- etc.

In my case, I was able to solve just by stopping and starting `boot2docker`:

```
$ bootdocker down
$ bootdocker up
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I kept getting this error while running `docker build`. Turns out my machine just ran out of storage space! Rebooting and deleting all my temp files fixed it.